# How to get current UTC time in unix format in jmeter

Tags: rest, http, testing, jmeter

I am testing a RestFul server which takes time stamp in header to evaluate expiry of http call, the server accepts UTC time in unix format 
Eg: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ number in this website.

so how to generate the time stamp and put it in header of http call in jmeter

[image]

I have used this approach, but when i convert it using the same website i have mentioned above it is giving me a wrong date

Answer (score 0):

Use [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function:

> The time function returns the current time in various formats.

Use the `${__time()}` in your header to get the time in Unix format.

Check this example:

[image]